# Kivy Treeview for a directory structure consumes lot of memory

Tags: python, kivy, treeview, directory-structure

I have an application which reads file from the usb drive to process further, So I have created the directory structure of the USB using the Treeview in Kivy. Each node of the Treeview is a Boxlayout which contains a Checkbox and a Label. We can select the files by clicking the Checkbox of respective File/Folder name. The challenge I am facing is if the directory structure contains more than 5000 files, the memory consumed is high when it is listed in the treeview and the application gets slow, if it is more than 10000 then the application freeze and sometime the application will get crash due to low memory.

Please find the below code, I am loading the files from the folder /USBDRIVE to load the files, kindly create the folder and have some files in it, then execute the below python program

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView , TreeViewNode
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.metrics import dp

import os
import subprocess
from functools import partial
import time


file_folder_select={}
selected_node=''
class MyEachNode(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.text = kwargs.pop('text', 'None')
        super(MyEachNode, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        global file_folder_select, selected_node
        self.orientation = 'horizontal'
        self.base_name=os.path.basename(self.text)
        self.parent_name=os.path.dirname(self.text)
        self.size_hint_y = None
        self.height = dp(60)
        self.padding=(20,0,20,0)
        # make the parts of the node
        self.lbl = Label(text=self.base_name, size_hint_x=0.5, halign="left", valign="center", bold=True, font_size=25)
        #self.chkbx_each_node = CheckBox(size_hint_x=0.01, color=(1, 1, 1, 3.5))  # alpha=3.5 to make it more visible
        self.chkbx_each_node=CheckBox(size_hint_x= None, size_hint_y= None, height=60, width=50)
        #self.chkbx_each_node.background_checkbox_normal = 'includes/unchecked.png'
        #self.chkbx_each_node.background_checkbox_down = 'includes/checked.png'
        file_folder_select[self.text]=self.chkbx_each_node
        self.chkbx_each_node.bind(active=self.on_checkbox_active)
        self.lbl.bind(size=self.lbl.setter('text_size'))
        # add the parts to the BoxLayout
        self.add_widget(self.chkbx_each_node)
        self.add_widget(self.lbl)
        #if os.path.isfile(self.text):
        try:
            file_folder_select[self.text].active=file_folder_select[self.parent_name].active
        except:
            pass
    def on_checkbox_active(self,checkbox, value):
        global selected_node
        if os.path.isdir(self.text):
            self.folder_files=subprocess.getoutput("find \'%s\'" %self.text)
            #for self.entries in  self.folder_files.splitlines()[:2]:
            if not selected_node in self.folder_files.splitlines():
                for self.entries in  self.folder_files.splitlines():
                    try:
                        file_folder_select[self.entries].active = value
                    except:
                        pass
            else:
                selected_node=''
            if value == False:
                try:
                    if file_folder_select[os.path.dirname(self.text)].active == True:
                        selected_node=str(self.text)
                    file_folder_select[os.path.dirname(self.text)].active = value
                except:
                    pass
                
        else:
            if value == False:
                #print(self.text)
                try:
                    if file_folder_select[os.path.dirname(self.text)].active == True:
                        selected_node=str(self.text)
                    file_folder_select[os.path.dirname(self.text)].active = value
                except:
                    pass
                
class MyTreeNode(MyEachNode, TreeViewNode):
    pass


class MyTreeView(TreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTreeView, self).__init__()
        self.size_hint_y=None
        self.bind(minimum_height=self.setter('height'))
        #self.on_node_expand=self.node_exp()
        self.bind(on_node_expand=self.node_exp)
        self.root_options={'text': 'USBDRIVE', 'bold':True, 'font_size':25}
        # The usb drive is mounted in /USBDRIVE or you can copy the files to /USBDRIVE
        self.my_drive='/USBDRIVE'
        self.extracted={}
        self.folder_files=subprocess.getoutput("find \'%s\' -maxdepth 1 " %self.my_drive)
        self.nodes={}
        self.create_nodes()
    def create_nodes(self, *largs):
        for self.entries in self.folder_files.splitlines():
            self.dir_name=os.path.dirname(self.entries)
            self.base_name=os.path.basename(self.entries)
            if  self.dir_name != "/":
                #if len(self.folder_files) <= 5500:
                    self.nodes[self.entries]=self.add_node(MyTreeNode(text=self.entries))
                    if os.path.isdir(self.entries):
                        self.nodes[self.entries].is_leaf=False
                # else:
                #     break
    def node_exp(self, node, exp_node):
        global running_windows, my_pid, file_manager_widget, file_folder_select
        self.exp_node=exp_node
        if not ( self.exp_node.text == 'USBDRIVE' or self.exp_node.text == 'DVDDRIVE'):
            if self.exp_node.is_loaded == False:
                self.keys = [self.k for self.k, self.v in self.nodes.items() if self.v == self.exp_node]
                self.folder_files=subprocess.getoutput("find \'%s\' -maxdepth 1 " %self.keys[0])
                Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.add_childs_inside_node, exp_node))

    def add_childs_inside_node(self,exp_node, *largs):
        global my_pid, running_windows, file_folder_select
        self.mycount=0
        for self.entries in self.folder_files.splitlines():
            # if len(file_folder_select) <= 5500:
                if self.mycount != 0:
                    if (self.mycount%1000) == 0 :
                        time.sleep(1)
                self.dir_name=os.path.dirname(self.entries)
                self.base_name=os.path.basename(self.entries)
                if  self.dir_name == self.keys[0]:
                    self.mycount+=1
                    self.nodes[self.entries]=self.add_node(MyTreeNode(text=self.entries),self.nodes[self.keys[0]])
                    if os.path.isdir(self.entries):
                        self.nodes[self.entries].is_leaf=False
            # else:
            #     break
        self.exp_node.is_loaded=True

    def hide_widget(self,wid, dohide):
        if hasattr(wid, 'saved_attrs'):
            if not dohide:
                wid.height, wid.size_hint_y, wid.opacity, wid.disabled = wid.saved_attrs
                del wid.saved_attrs
        elif dohide:
            wid.saved_attrs = wid.height, wid.size_hint_y, wid.opacity, wid.disabled
            wid.height, wid.size_hint_y, wid.opacity, wid.disabled = 0, None, 0, True







class FilelistApp(App):
       
    def build(self):
        
        MainBox = BoxLayout()
        InsideBox=BoxLayout(size_hint_y=.9)
        self.file_folder_tree=MyTreeView()
        self.scroll_view=ScrollView(size_hint=(1, 1),do_scroll_y=True,size=InsideBox.size)
        self.scroll_view.pos_hint_x=0
        self.scroll_view.pos_hint_y=1
        MainBox.add_widget(InsideBox)
        InsideBox.add_widget(self.scroll_view)
        self.scroll_view.add_widget(self.file_folder_tree)
 
        return MainBox
 
root = FilelistApp()
   

root.run()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: because its wrong to do that. if u are to handle large data u cant just load all to memory either **u load it part by part for example bind ur tree to a scrollview that loads from y=y1 to y=y2** or more efficiently ** insert the file lists  into a database** and selecet into the scrollview afterwards u can check and uncheck.  that database looks like this (check=bool, path='string') and then u can handle paths by split.path or many other solutions

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, honestly I am not a core developer and new to python/kivy . I am loading the nodes part by part when the folders are expanded. but if a folder contains more than 5000 files then this could cause issue as well.